# Command for two arithmetic conditions

Tags: linux

Given a CSV file, I am trying to determine which rows have a value greater than 10,000,000 in column 3 (Units) AND also a value less than 50 in column 4 (Cost). From there, I need to output all rows that satisfy those two conditions. The following command is my attempt, but it does not execute.

`awk '$3 > 10000000 && $4 < 50 {print $0}’ filename.csv`

I believe that this is due to the "print" condition, but I'm unsure how to modify it to display the result of the 2 conditions. The following is a part of my input file. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

| Name | Weight | Units | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 438943 | 10043782000 | 42 |
| Item 2 | 32882 | 21845339 | 51 |
| Item 3 | 318918 | 43903882 | 30 |
| Item 4 | 218921 | 49438943242 | 79 |

Comment: open the manual of `awk` and check how the fields are defined

Answer (score 1):

Try `-F`:

```bsh
awk -F , '$3 > 10000000 && $4 < 50 {print $0}' filename.csv
```

Comment: This worked; thank you so much! I have a question regarding the "awk" command. When do you know when to add -F?

Comment: You can find the answer by `man awk | grep -F -- -F`. By default, `awk` uses space and tab as field separator.

Comment: @c200402 Note that it's `-F ,` to change the default input field separator to a comma, not just `-F`.